# Is a unique_ptr with custom deleter never invoked when initialized with nullptr

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, unique-ptr

In scenarios where you interface with C libraries which manage the creation/deletion of pointers, I saw a recent buggy code where a struct was managed by a unique_ptr before the pointer was actually pointing to a valid memory location, so the raw ptr was nullptr before it was passed on to a C API. An example in code to simulate this:

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
struct Foo {
  std::string s;
};
// A simple fn to simulate C libararies which use a outptr
void init_foo(Foo** foo_ptr_ptr) {
    std::cout << "Initializing Foo\n"; 
    Foo* f = new Foo; 
    *foo_ptr_ptr = f;
};
// custom resource deletion via the C API
void delete_foo(Foo* foo) {
    std::cout << "Invoking destructor!\n";
  if (foo != nullptr) {
    std::cout << "Deleting Foo\n";
    delete foo;
  } 
}

int main() {
    Foo * foo {nullptr};
    // Ideally you should init_foo(&foo) here before creating a uniq_ptr
    std::unique_ptr<Foo, decltype(&delete_foo)> foo_ptr {foo, &delete_foo};
    init_foo(&foo); // Buggy initialization, however delete_foo will never be invoked!
    return 0;
}
```

In case of a buggy initialization ie. you create the unique_ptr with ptr constructor before the ptr was actually valid, and you initialize it later what actually happens, is the destructor never invoked because it is UB to change the memory location of unique_ptr's managed raw ptr?

For eg. in the above code where `init_foo` was called after unique_ptr was created, the destructor of the unique_ptr was never invoked. Is this because this is a Undefined behaviour?

Of course calling the unique_ptr after init_foo will have the expected behaviour where the construction and the expected destructor is called.

Comment: `foo_ptr` is still null, you haven't changed its value, it took a copy of the value of `foo` when it was constructed, not a reference

Comment: If the managed pointer is not null, then the custom deleter is not used.    This is a consequence of statements in the standard that the destructor (and other members that release the managed object using the deleter) of `unique_ptr` have no effect if the managed pointer is null.    Among other things, this means the custom deleter can ASSUME it can safely release the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] what actually happens, is the destructor never invoked because it is UB to change the memory location of unique_ptr's managed raw ptr?

You never change the pointer managed by the `std::unique_ptr` to anything other than null and that's why the `delete_foo` is never invoked, not even with null as parameter. There's no undefined behaviour happending here, it's just that the code posted in the question doesn't behave the way you expect it to.

`std::unique_ptr` contains a member variable holding the pointer and the constructor you're using in the question takes the pointer by value, i.e. it copies the current value of `foo` resulting in later changes of the value of `foo` in having no effect on `foo_ptr`.

You could either call `init_foo(&foo)` before calling the constructor or provide the `std::unique_ptr` with ownership of the object later using `std::unique_ptr::reset`:

```
Foo* foo{ nullptr };
// Ideally you should init_foo(&foo) here before creating a uniq_ptr
std::unique_ptr<Foo, decltype(&delete_foo)> foo_ptr{ foo, &delete_foo };
init_foo(&foo); // Buggy initialization, however delete_foo will never be invoked!
foo_ptr.reset(foo);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, now I understood why the value change wasn't reflected, however my other question is a unique_ptr with custom deleter never invoked if it was set to nullptr already, like is there any way that "Invoking destructor" (and not "Deleting foo") fn gets printed on nullptr?

Comment: @xworder From the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/~unique_ptr): If `get() == nullptr` there are no effects.  So, in a word, no (and that can be useful sometimes).

Comment: @xworder The deleted isn't used unless the pointer is non-null, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/%7Eunique_ptr

Comment: If you want to change this, it's simple enough to create your own type owning the pointer `template<class T, class Deleter> class MyUniquePtr { T* m_ptr; [[no_unique_address]] Deleter m_deleter; MyUniquePtr(T* ptr = nullptr, Deleter del = {}) : m_ptr(ptr), m_del(std::move(del)) {} ~MyUniquePtr() { m_del(ptr); } MyUniquePtr(MyUniquePtr&& other) noexcept : m_ptr(other.m_ptr) { other.m_ptr = nullptr; } MyUniquePtr& operator=(MyUniquePtr&& other) noexcept { m_del(m_ptr); m_ptr = other.m_ptr; other.m_ptr = nullptr; return *this; }  };`